# FindElements is not returning all matched elements

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium C#.  Here is the html that I'm searching (please excuse the spelling - it is not a transcription error):

```
<td class="Search3-product-cell" align="left">
  <div class="SearchRersultsNameCell">
    <a id="MainPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_SearchMatrix_SearchResultView_ProductNameLink_33" class="Name">Tango 6 Pc. Queen Bedroom Set</a>
    <br/>
    <a id="MainPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_SearchMatrix_SearchResultView_ProductPriceLink_33">$1,999.00</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

I have an IWebElement reference (x) to the td element.  But I have not been able to 'see' the second anchor element inside it.  I have tried two primary ways.

Method 1:

```
foreach (IWebElement we in x.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))) // for each anchor element
{
     if (we.GetAttribute("class").Equals("Name"))
     {
        name = we.Text;
     }
     else
     {
        price = Util.ConvertCurrencyToDecimal(we.Text);
     }
}
```

With this code, it never sees the second anchor (the one without 'class="Name"').

The second method is:

```
IWebElement x = elem.FindElement(By.ClassName("SearchRersultsNameCell"));
myLocator = By.CssSelector("a[id^='MainPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_SearchMatrix_SearchResultView_ProductNameLink_']");
if (SeleniumHelpers.IsElementPresentNoWait(elem, myLocator))
{
    name = x.FindElement(myLocator).Text;
}
else
{
    name = "Name not found";
}

myLocator = By.CssSelector("a[id^='MainPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_SearchMatrix_SearchResultView_ProductPriceLink_']");
if (SeleniumHelpers.IsElementPresentNoWait(elem, myLocator))
{
    price = x.FindElement(myLocator).Text;
}
else
{
    price = -1;
}
```

Again, in neither case does the code see the second anchor.

What am I missing??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried calling the second element using `By.className="Name"`?

Comment: The second anchor element does not have a class attribute, so searching By.ClassName("Name") would only find the first anchor, which both of my methods see (to get the product name).  But I can't see the price element.

Comment: Your first code works fine for me...so what does `x.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))` return? A collection of 1 element inside? What browser is this in? In your second portion of code, I'd assume you mean that instead of `price` becoming `1,999.00` it is simply `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
if (we.GetAttribute("class").Equals("Name"))
```

`GetAttribute()` will return `null` if the attribute doesn't exist. In this example, the second `a` tag doesn't have the `class` attribute and returns `null`. Calling `Equals()` on `null` results in a null pointer exception, causing at least the for loop to exit.

Documentation on the `GetAttribute()` method:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)

Comment: Charlie:  Dang! Thank you - You're right - I'll fix that!  However, the exception doesn't happen because that code never gets executed because FindElements doesn't return the <a> that has a null class attribute (as seen in the second method using By.CssSelector).

Comment: In your second example the IDs you are searching for both end in an underscore where the id's don't actually have underscores at the end

Comment: Yes - I am using the id^= construct to match any element whose id starts with that string.  I admit, I've used that only once before, but successfully as far as I can tell, so I'm not completely confident that I'm using it correctly.  However, since using that construct does find the first anchor with ProductNameLink, I have to assume it should work for the second anchor with ProductPriceLink.  But it still isn't finding it.

Comment: Both of your examples rely on other code to "know" that either element was found. Have you considered printing out the id of every element that is found or the path of every element that is found immediately after searching for it? This will help identify if the FindElement method is failing or if another part of your code is failing. If it really is the FindElement method that is failing, I suggest simplifying the question and omitting the extra code.

Comment: If that "[id^=...]" selector actually ignores that last underscore, the CSS selector implementation that is used by Selenium is broken. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Printing out each element's TagName demonstrates that FindElements is only returning the first anchor and the br elements.  The second anchor element is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

My profound apologies.  It turns out Selenium is working correctly - and returning all elements.  The problem was there was a subtle difference in the configuration used when running the automated tests and how I was running the browser manually, resulting in different browser page content.  Sorry for wasting people's time!  Color me embarrassed.